# M1 Mac - Running rspec on capybara tests yields fork() unimplemented on this machine error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

I recently updated rvm from ruby-3.1.0 to ruby-3.1.2 and am now experiencing errors when trying to run feature specs via rspec.

I believe I have uninstalled 3.1.0 via `rvm uninstall ruby-3.1.0` and have run `bundle install` to make sure my gems are present. I have also reinstalled ruby-3.1.2 via rvm.

Here is an example stacktrace when running `bundle exec rspec [filename_spec.rb]`:

```
NotImplementedError:
            fork() function is unimplemented on this machine
          # /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/childprocess-4.1.0/lib/childprocess/unix/fork_exec_process.rb:20:in `fork'
          # /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/childprocess-4.1.0/lib/childprocess/unix/fork_exec_process.rb:20:in `launch_process'
          # /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/childprocess-4.1.0/lib/childprocess/abstract_process.rb:81:in `start'
          # /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.5.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service_manager.rb:109:in `start_process'
          # /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.5.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service_manager.rb:56:in `block in start'
          # /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.5.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_lock.rb:41:in `locked'
          # /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.5.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service_manager.rb:54:in `start'
          # /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.5.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:84:in `launch'
          # /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.5.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:341:in `service_url'
          # /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.5.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:321:in `create_bridge'
          # /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.5.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:74:in `initialize'
          # /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.5.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:47:in `new'
          # /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.5.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:47:in `for'
          # /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.5.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:89:in `for'
          # /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/capybara-3.36.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:83:in `browser'
          # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:143:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Check your `gem env` and `ruby -v` to see what Ruby you're running. It's odd that it's not implemented, as that is usually a Windows-specific thing.